# ID3 Decision tree using web2py

Tags: model-view-controller, tree, web2py, decision-tree

I would just like to ask how to create a non-database application in web2py using MVC implementation in python.

I am working on a thesis about creating/building an id3 decision tree and i decided to make it web-based. Most of the examples in web2py are utilizing database. My thesis will only require an uploaded file which contains my dataset. After uploading, it will automatically be transformed into a decision tree.

I know it's quite confusing but I appreciate, if there's anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a database to use web2py. You just need to write the proper code to upload and process your file, and that will depend on the details of your application. Here's a simple example:

```
def id3_tree():
    form = FORM(INPUT(_name='Data', _type='file'),
        INPUT(_type='submit', _value='Submit'))
    if request.vars.Data:
        tree = create_tree(request.vars.Data.file)
    else:
        tree = 'No tree yet'
    return dict(form=form, tree=tree)
```

That will create a form for uploading a data file. Once the file is uploaded, the code calls a `create_tree()` function and passes the file object to it (request.vars.Data.file will be a cStringIO.StringO object containing the file contents -- see http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html).

Note, this method does not actually save the file. As an alternative, you could save the file and then open the saved file in order to process it. In that case, you could use [`SQLFORM.factory()`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#SQLFORM.factory) and take advantage of web2py's built-in file upload functionality.

If you have questions as you proceed, feel free to ask on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer. I`ve tried it and it worked. now, I am confused as to where to insert my computations for entropy and information gain to be used in building the tree. shall i make something like:

def create_tree():
   .....
so that i can insert my codes in here or i will put it after 

tree = create_tree(request.vars.Data.file) ?

Comment: Your data file is in `request.vars.Data.file` -- you can call as many functions as you want to process that and produce a result, and then return that result in the `id3_tree()` dict. The functions you use to do the processing can be defined (a) elsewhere in the controller, (b) in a model file, or (c) in a module (which requires importing).